# asp.net-core MVC rc2 using net451 on linux

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-rc2

I am trying to migrate my website from dotnet core rc1 to dotnet core rc2, but I faced an error, then I tried to run a small test and it also didn't work for me.
This is my teste: https://github.com/ricardoalcantara/WebApplicationBasic

My environment is:

- Debian 8.4
- Mono 4.2.3
- dotnet 1.0.0-preview1-002702

I need to run it on top of the "framework": "net451" because my main project needs few libs which still just run on that platform, so I am running with this command line:

```
dotnet run --framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1
```

it actually runs, but when I try to access localhost:5000 it throws a long stack error mainly with that message:

```
z2cw6v06.4ja(43,10): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
z2cw6v06.4ja(43,50): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
z2cw6v06.4ja(43,10): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
z2cw6v06.4ja(45,10): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
z2cw6v06.4ja(45,10): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
z2cw6v06.4ja(45,50): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
z2cw6v06.4ja(45,10): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
z2cw6v06.4ja(47,10): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
z2cw6v06.4ja(47,10): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
z2cw6v06.4ja(47,50): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

Can someone help me to solve that problem?

Obs.: It works on windows.

Comment: Try `dotnet run --framework net451`

Comment: Still doesn't work, but I believe I found a workaround to temporally fix it. I will update this after I have it tested.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, the error seems to be that MVC is failing to compile the view:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
pufduf6v.a1v(17,88): error CS1980: Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
pufduf6v.a1v(17,88): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
pufduf6v.a1v(17,47): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
…
```

But running `dotnet publish` and then executing the result directly using `mono` works for me, e.g. (on Ubuntu):

```
mono bin/Debug/net451/ubuntu.14.04-x64/publish/WebApplicationBasic.exe
```

[As was already explained to you on Github, this seems to be a known issue.](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4818#issuecomment-224167616)

Comment: I have already understood that it's a known issue, but I am seeking a way to make it work anyway. I am testing a possible solution posted there, when I have it done I will update if it has fully solved my problem.